# Selenium with maven cannot detect webelements it was able to detect without maven

Tags: java, html, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I have converted my selenium TestNG project to maven, and wrote the same command on the same webelement, in the non maven version the object was detected, but in the maven one it could not find it (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

this was the command:

```html
                        // Define Ad
                        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                                (By.cssSelector("span.close.js-rebateHook")));
                        WebElement Ad_X = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.close.js-rebateHook"));
                        
                        // Closes ad if exists
                        if (Ad_X.isDisplayed()) {
                            //act.doubleClick(Ad_X).perform();
                            Ad_X.click();
                            System.out.println("Closed Ad");
                        }
                        else {
                            ;
                        }
```

this was the console result on the maven run:

```html
[ERROR] Logo_Exsists(testcases.OpenZafulTest)  Time elapsed: 7.9 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Coordinates
    at testcases.OpenZafulTest.Logo_Exsists(OpenZafulTest.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Coordinates
    at testcases.OpenZafulTest.Logo_Exsists(OpenZafulTest.java:53)
```

this was the console result on the non maven run (printed, and also closed the ad) :

```html
Closed Ad
```

and this is my pom.xml (very messy at this point, I am stucked on this for a long time and tried adding and removing and changing a lot of my dependencies according to many examples I saw online):

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ZafulSelMaven4</groupId>
  <artifactId>ZafulSelMaven4</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  
  <name>ZafulSelMaven4</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
 <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache 2</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.argument.target>${maven.compiler.target}</maven.compiler.argument.target>
        <maven.compiler.argument.source>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.argument.source>
        <appium-java-client.version>7.1.0</appium-java-client.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--Dependency Versions-->
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.15.0</assertj-core.version>
        <testng.version>7.1.0</testng.version>
        <query.version>2.0.0-BETA3</query.version>
        <!--Plugin Versions-->
        <driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin.version>1.0.18</driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <!--Configuration Properties-->
        <overwrite.binaries>false</overwrite.binaries>
        <read.timeout>30000</read.timeout>
        <connection.timeout>40000</connection.timeout>
        <retry.attempts>4</retry.attempts>
        <browser>chrome</browser>
        <threads>1</threads>
        <remote>false</remote>
        <headless>true</headless>
        <seleniumGridURL/>
        <platform/>
        <browserVersion/>
        <proxyEnabled>false</proxyEnabled>
        <proxyHost/>
        <proxyPort/>
        <proxyUsername/>
        <proxyPassword/>
        
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${appium-java-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
              <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>query</artifactId>
            <version>${query.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
          <groupId>org.json</groupId>
          <artifactId>json</artifactId>
          <version>20170516</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
         <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.1</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency> 
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>selenium-tests</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        <configuration>                                          
                         <suiteXmlFiles>
                          <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>               
                         </suiteXmlFiles>   
                         <suitename>Test_Suite</suitename>     
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/selenium_standalone_binaries</rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                            <downloadedZipFileDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/selenium_standalone_zips</downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                            <customRepositoryMap>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/RepositoryMap.xml</customRepositoryMap>
                            <overwriteFilesThatExist>${overwrite.binaries}</overwriteFilesThatExist>
                            <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>false</onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                            <fileDownloadRetryAttempts>${retry.attempts}</fileDownloadRetryAttempts>
                            <fileDownloadReadTimeout>${read.timeout}</fileDownloadReadTimeout>
                            <operatingSystems>
                                <windows>true</windows>
                                <linux>true</linux>
                                <mac>true</mac>
                            </operatingSystems>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>selenium</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <browser>${browser}</browser>
                                <screenshotDirectory>${project.build.directory}/screenshots</screenshotDirectory>
                                <remoteDriver>${remote}</remoteDriver>
                                <gridURL>${seleniumGridURL}</gridURL>
                                <desiredPlatform>${platform}</desiredPlatform>
                                <desiredBrowserVersion>${browserVersion}</desiredBrowserVersion>
                                <proxyEnabled>${proxyEnabled}</proxyEnabled>
                                <proxyHost>${proxyHost}</proxyHost>
                                <proxyPort>${proxyPort}</proxyPort>
                                <proxyUsername>${proxyUsername}</proxyUsername>
                                <proxyPassword>${proxyPassword}</proxyPassword>
                                <headless>${headless}</headless>

                                <!--Set properties passed in by the driver binary downloader-->
                                <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                                <webdriver.ie.driver>${webdriver.ie.driver}</webdriver.ie.driver>
                                <webdriver.opera.driver>${webdriver.opera.driver}</webdriver.opera.driver>
                                <webdriver.gecko.driver>${webdriver.gecko.driver}</webdriver.gecko.driver>
                                <webdriver.edge.driver>${webdriver.edge.driver}</webdriver.edge.driver>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <!--This goal makes the build fail if you have test failures-->
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

If anyone knows the reason for this problem or how to fix it, it would help a lot

Comment: how you are running test? simply running class? or mvn command?

Comment: I run the pom.xml with "Run as maven test", and it refers to the testng.xml file

Comment: try once mvn clean and mvn compile.

Comment: Tried it now, nothing changed, the exact same problem happened again

Comment: so you haven't seen any compile issues.. paste complete console exception when u ran test. its something related ur maven config. not able to find that class

Answer (score 0):

your project got broken when you converted it, right click the project, go to maven and update the project

Comment: I already updated the did the maven>Update project, many times, it did not solve it

Comment: okay, without seeing your actual projects its will be hard to tell, refer to this and may possibly help - https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html.